# How to use distinct with inner join having sub query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want UserId from the transaction table should be distinct so can u please tell me how i can get distinct userid form the transaction table having inner join?

```
SELECT     TransactionMaster.TransId, TransactionMaster.UserId, TransactionMaster.SessionId, TransactionMaster.TotalAmount, TransactionMaster.PaymentStatus, 
                      TransactionMaster.TransDate, TransactionMaster.ShippingId, TransactionMaster.IPAddress, TransactionMaster.IsShipped, TransactionMaster.DeliveredDate, 
                      Register.ID, Register.Password, Register.FirstName, Register.LastName, Register.MiddleName, Register.Address, Register.CountryId, Register.StateId, 
                      Register.CityId, Register.Email, Register.Status, Register.IPAddress AS Expr1, Register.Account, Register.ZipCode
FROM         TransactionMaster INNER JOIN
                      Register ON TransactionMaster.UserId = Register.ID
WHERE(TransactionMaster.UserId IN (SELECT Distinct UserId FROM TransactionMaster WHERE TransactionMaster.UserId IN(SELECT  UserId FROM TransactionMaster)))
```

Right now i get ouput :

```
**Transid                              UserId        sessioId            otherfields**

Ai36Lft9X4PrHg8p7BTs2n5K5Dcz4E        z8CFj92M     dzwsyf55s1io1e552ifty555
d3YAs6j4L2SxJm95PeDn78NbCq49By        f4M5Rmr9     1u0mkd45rt5jz455axcvbgbd
k6Z5LiYp39CnBs24Gca8D7Sfw8J6Xd        f4M5Rmr9     zo1gwz45gtbg3uegkkf21dmz
```

But i want this type output

```
**Transid                                  UserId        sessioId       otherfields**

Ai36Lft9X4PrHg8p7BTs2n5K5Dcz4E        z8CFj92M     dzwsyf55s1io1e552ifty555
d3YAs6j4L2SxJm95PeDn78NbCq49By        f4M5Rmr9     1u0mkd45rt5jz455axcvbgbd
```

Comment: try using some alias in the subquery for transaction master

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [cte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get distinct userid.
Here is a simplified version that you should be able apply to your more complicated query.

```
declare @T table(TransID varchar(50), UserID varchar(8), SessionID varchar(50))

insert into @T values
('Ai36Lft9X4PrHg8p7BTs2n5K5Dcz4E',        'z8CFj92M',     'dzwsyf55s1io1e552ifty555'),
('d3YAs6j4L2SxJm95PeDn78NbCq49By',        'f4M5Rmr9',     '1u0mkd45rt5jz455axcvbgbd'),
('k6Z5LiYp39CnBs24Gca8D7Sfw8J6Xd',        'f4M5Rmr9',     'zo1gwz45gtbg3uegkkf21dmz')

;with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by UserID order by SessionID) as rn
  from @T
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Result

```
TransID                        UserID   SessionID                rn
d3YAs6j4L2SxJm95PeDn78NbCq49By f4M5Rmr9 1u0mkd45rt5jz455axcvbgbd 1
Ai36Lft9X4PrHg8p7BTs2n5K5Dcz4E z8CFj92M dzwsyf55s1io1e552ifty555 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by UserId and decide which aggregation is right for the rest of the columns. I think that might get hard...

Your problem is, that a distinct selection always works on all columns. So your only way is to group, but having a group requires you to have a aggregation function on every column you want to display. You provided far to less information of what you want to have a clue if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

**First store the upcoming output in temp table(#TempTrans) then do this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM #TempTrans
```

Comment: As there are more than one sessionIds for a user and a sessionId should be part of the output a distinct selection wouldn't help him. If only the userid is required then a distinct would help: SELECT     DISTINCT TransactionMaster.UserId FROM ...